# What is the difference between setting the argument to @GeneratedValue and not setting it?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

What is the difference between setting the argument to `@GeneratedValue` and not setting it?

```kotlin
@Entity
class User(
    var firstName: String,
    var lastName: String,
    @Id @GeneratedValue 
    var id: Long? = null
)

@Entity
class User(
    var firstName: String = "",
    var lastName: String = "",
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = 0
)
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and show us how the results of your own research aren't enough to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@GeneratedValue` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` is same.

`GenerationType.AUTO` is default.

[GeneratedValue (Java EE 6 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html)

> strategy
>
> public abstract GenerationType strategy
>
> (Optional) The primary key generation strategy that the persistence provider must use to generate the annotated entity primary key.
>
> Default:
>   javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO